# Check if an element exists in a dynamic allocated array C++

Tags: c++

For example, in Python, I could do:

```
if 'a' in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
   return 'Hi'
```

But in C++, I'm not sure what the equivalent function for that is.

Comment: Like this? `std::vector<std::string> x = {"a","b","c"}; if(x.end() != std::find(x.begin(),x.end(),"a")) return "Hi";`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from `<algorithm>`:

```
std::vector<char> dynamic_array{'a', 'b', 'c'};
auto exists = std::find(dynamic_array.begin(), dynamic_array.end(), 'a')
                  != dynamic_array.end();
```

You can create a function if you find yourself doing this a lot:

```
template<typename Container, typename T>
bool contains(Container const& container, T const& value) {
    using std::begin;
    return std::find(begin(container), end(container), value)
               != end(container);
}
```

Comment: I would say this is one of the cases where the `auto` keyword is overused.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I would say there is no case where the `auto` keyword can be overused. Actually, if this was C++14 I would have specified `auto` as the return type of `contains`.

Comment: I would say this is one of the cases where the _upvote_ button is overused.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library containers are really the way to go in C++.

std::vector is the default sequence, but you could also use std::set or others, depending on your use case.

If you don't know which one to use, stick with std::vector until you have a compelling reason for others.

This site contains some sample code:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

However, I've been told that the following site is more peer reviewed:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector